# Do cave spiders only spawn from their respective spawners or do they also spawn naturally in abandoned mineshafts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and my friend had an argument over this, him saying they can only spawn with the help of spawners. Though I vaguely remember seeing one in an abandoned mineshaft AND a normal cave. It was a few years ago that I had seen 'em, so I don't really trust my memory.

Answer (score 2):

The [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cave_Spider) states that they only spawn from the spawners.

Once a spawners is removed, or [nullified](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/125130/73976), they will no longer spawn.